# Where in django docs i can find more info on "_Meta.get_field_by_name"

Tags: django, django-models, documentation

I want to read more information about the function i can use with _Meta like `.fields` and `get_field_by_name` but i could not find in django official docs.

Can anyone give the links where on their docs they explain the function avaiable with `_Meta`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the reason why not much documentation is available in the official docs: _meta is named according to the Python convention where an underscore denotes that the variable is a private attribute.

So _meta is (generally) for Django's internal uses and its mechanics are not guaranteed to remain unchanged over time. Consequently using it is not encouraged.

Nevertheless, here's a relevant link from the first page from a google search: http://readthedocs.org/projects/django-model-_meta-reference/

Comment: Thanks buddy , that was good site